# How to convert the following dataframe/dataset to nested json as desired format?

Tags: python-3.x

The data set are follows:

```
id,date,diastolic,systolic,drugs_name,drugs_type,drugs_unit,drugs_dosage,drugs_time

10001,2020-09-15,70,120,paracetamol,tablet,1,twice a day,after meal
10001,2020-09-15,70,120,ursocol,tablet,1,twice a day,before meal
10001,2020-09-15,70,120,rectacare,ointment,1,use once a day,any time
10001,2020-11-11,85,135,metronidazole,tablet,1,trice a day,after meal
10001,2020-11-11,85,135,antacid,tablet,1,twice a day,before meal
```

My desire output is as follow:

```
 [
    {
        "date": "2020-09-15",
        **"bp":{"diastolic": 70, "systolic": 120},**
        "drugs": [
            {
                "drugs_name": "paracetamol",
                "drugs_type": "tablet",
                "drugs_unit": "1",
                "drugs_dosage": "twice a day",
                "drugs_time": "after meal"
            },
            {
                "drugs_name": "ursocol",
                "drugs_type": "tablet",
                "drugs_unit": "1",
                "drugs_dosage": "twice a day",
                "drugs_time": "before meal"
            },
            {
                "drugs_name": "rectacare",
                "drugs_type": "ointment",
                "drugs_unit": "1",
                "drugs_dosage": "use once a day",
                "drugs_time": "any time"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-11-11",
        **"bp":{"diastolic": 85,"systolic": 135}**,
        "drugs": [
            {
                "drugs_name": "metronidazole",
                "drugs_type": "tablet",
                "drugs_unit": "1",
                "drugs_dosage": "trice a day",
                "drugs_time": "after meal"
            },
            {
                "drugs_name": "antacid",
                "drugs_type": "tablet",
                "drugs_unit": "1",
                "drugs_dosage": "twice a day",
                "drugs_time": "before meal"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I wrote a code stated here:

```
df['date']=df.date.apply(lambda x: x.strftime(format_str))
json_ofmysqlDataframe = (
          sql_df.groupby(['date','diastolic','systolic'])
         .apply(lambda x: x[['drugs_name', 'drugs_type', 'drugs_unit', 'drugs_dosage', 'drugs_time']].to_dict('r'))
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns={0:'drugs'})                         
         .to_json(orient='records')             
         )  
loaded_json=json.loads(json_ofmysqlDataframe)
json_convert=json.dumps(loaded_json,indent=4, sort_keys=False)
print("\n\n\n",json_convert,"\n\n")
```

The output was as follows:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2020-09-15",
        **"diastolic": 70,
        "systolic": 120,**
        "drugs": [
            {
                "drugs_name": "paracetamol",
                "drugs_type": "tablet",
                "drugs_unit": "1",
                "drugs_dosage": "twice a day",
                "drugs_time": "after meal"
            },
            {
                "drugs_name": "ursocol",
                "drugs_type": "tablet",
                "drugs_unit": "1",
                "drugs_dosage": "twice a day",
                "drugs_time": "before meal"
            },
            {
                "drugs_name": "rectacare",
                "drugs_type": "ointment",
                "drugs_unit": "1",
                "drugs_dosage": "use once a day",
                "drugs_time": "any time"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-11-11",
        **"diastolic": 85,
        "systolic": 135,**
        "drugs": [
            {
                "drugs_name": "metronidazol",
                "drugs_type": "tablet",
                "drugs_unit": "1",
                "drugs_dosage": "trice a day",
                "drugs_time": "after meal"
            },
            {
                "drugs_name": "antacid",
                "drugs_type": "tablet",
                "drugs_unit": "1",
                "drugs_dosage": "twice a day",
                "drugs_time": "before meal"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Would please help me to get "bp" in desired format?

Comment: Can you put the json in a code formatter like you did your code so that it's easier to see the structure?